# Copy-pasting text from generated PDF using PDFBox results in garbage

Tags: java, pdf, fonts, copy-paste, pdfbox

I have some code that takes a template PDF, creates a new PDF, overlays the new PDF over the template PDF and writes the result to a stream. All this using PDFBox 2.0.4.

The problem is that copy-pasting text from the generated PDF to a text editor results in garbage text.

This happens only for the text that was added by my code, the text in the original template still works fine. The text that I add gets added using a custom font.

How do I fix the generated PDF so that the text can be copy-pasted?

SSCCE:

```
public class PDFTest {

    private static final String FONT = "/fonts/font.ttf";

    public static void main(final String... args) throws IOException, FontFormatException {
        final Overlay overlay = new Overlay();
        overlay.setInputPDF(newDocument("Input text", 400));
        overlay.setAllPagesOverlayPDF(newDocument("Test text", 200));

        try (final PDDocument document = overlay.overlay(new HashMap<>())) {
            document.save("example.pdf");
        }
    }

    private static PDDocument newDocument(final String text, final int offsetY) throws IOException, FontFormatException {
        final PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
        document.addPage(insertTextInPage(document, text, offsetY));
        return document;
    }

    private static PDPage insertTextInPage(final PDDocument document, final String text, final int offsetY) throws IOException, FontFormatException {
        try (final InputStream fontStream = PDFTest.class.getResourceAsStream(FONT)) {
            final PDFont normalFont = PDType0Font.load(document, fontStream);

            final PDPage page = new PDPage();
            try (final PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, APPEND, false)) {
                addTextBlock(contentStream, normalFont, text, offsetY);
            }
            return page;
        }
    }

    private static void addTextBlock(final PDPageContentStream contentStream, final PDFont font, final String text, final int offsetY)
            throws IOException {
        contentStream.beginText();
        contentStream.setFont(font, 16);
        contentStream.newLineAtOffset(20, offsetY);
        contentStream.showText(text);
        contentStream.endText();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share an example pair of PDFs before and after your manipulation. Also please show enough code to allow reproducing the issue (i.e. preferably a [sscce](http://sscce.org)).

Comment: Please mention what PDFBox version you're using.

Comment: @Tilman done. As a side note I also tried using version 2.0.8 but it resulted in garbled text so I reverted back to the version I started with.

Comment: How was your contentStream created? If you can't share your PDFs, please try reproducing with publicly available PDFs.

Comment: @mkl I added the SSCCE, the only thing missing is the font. Stackoverflow doesn't have an upload feature so I can't put it anywhere. The font is relevant, if I replace it with one of the built-in ones the problem doesn't occur.

Comment: *"Stackoverflow doesn't have an upload feature so I can't put it anywhere."* - Usually one shares the file in question using a public googledrive or dropbox share (other file sharing platforms may work, too, but no ads or fly-by manipulators, please) and posts the URL here.

Comment: @mkl the font: https://filebin.ca/3keX29HmQs1F/font.ttf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue ([PDFBOX-3243](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3243)), files constructed with subsetted fonts (you are using `PDType0Font.load()` which is very efficient) are in an intermediate state until they get saved, which is the time when the subsetting takes place.

Solution for you: either save and reload, or save to a dummy. In Windows I changed `newDocument` like this and it worked:

```
private static PDDocument newDocument(final String text, final int offsetY) throws IOException, FontFormatException
{
    final PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
    document.addPage(insertTextInPage(document, text, offsetY));
    document.save("nul"); // NEW!
    return document;
}
```

Comment: yes that works for me too. Although I did this: `document.save(new ByteArrayOutputStream());` to prevent the writing of an actual file.

Comment: Turns out that PDDocument doesn't hang on or need in any way this OutputStream. So I used a NopOutputstream; `private static class NopOutputStream extends OutputStream {
        public void write(int b) throws IOException {}
        public void write(byte b[]) throws IOException {}
        public void write(byte b[], int off, int len) throws IOException {}
    }`